# Common Doubt: What did I do wrong here?-Number of ways to arrange green and blue bottles........

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, permutations, combinations, self-learning

> Number of ways in which $7$ green bottles and $8$ blue bottles can be arranged in a row if exactly $1$ pair of green bottles is side by side, is ______
>
> Note-Assume all bottles to be alike except for the color.

**Attempt**

```
                  _|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
```

$8$ Blue bottles firstly arranged in $1$ ways only since all are identical. Now selected $2$ green bottles in $1$ way only again as it is identical. Now the $6$ elements ($1$ pair bottles and $5$ bottles green in color) can be placed into $^9C_6$ which is equal to $84$ ways. But the answer in answer key is $504$ ways.

> Where is the fault in my process? I tried to think about the flaw but couldn't encounter on it.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from keeping two blue bottles side by side...

Comment: But doesn't the selection of places for green bottles ensure that case for blue bottles also?

Comment: The order of single and double green bottles is important.

Comment: Doing it with $\binom96$ you overlook that the spot of the $2$ green bottles matters. E.g. bggbgbgbgbgbgbb and bgbggbgbgbgbgbb are essentially different.

Comment: @drhab How it is "overlooked" if I chose 6 places? Wouldn't that pair will be arranged in that 6th place also?

Comment: $\binom96$ comes to selecting $6$ spots. But one of these spots must be looked at as a special spot. It is the spot where not $1$ but $2$ green bottles are placed. For this special spot there are $9$ options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing it with $\binom96$ you overlook that the spot of the $2$ green bottles matters.

E.g. bggbgbgbgbgbgbb and bgbggbgbgbgbgbb are essentially different.

---

Place $8$ blue bottles.

Then for the **couple** of green bottles there are $9$ spots.

After that there are $8$ spots left for the remaining $5$ green bottles.

Result: $$9\binom85=504$$possibilities.

Comment: Understood your point. Thanks for the example. Made me realise where I was wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome.